# How can I request iOS storage permission in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have found a package called [react-native-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions) which gives most of the permissions in Android and iOS. Currently it is not supporting Storage permission in iOS. How can I request iOS storage permission in react native?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the following fields in your plist.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>*your app name* would like to save photos from the app to your gallery</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>*your app name* would like to access your photo gallery for uploading images to the app</string>
```

Comment: I'm specifically looking for iOS permissions. Can you provide more info about the .plist usage?

Comment: Is there any way to ask camera permission at the launch of the application like push notification permission? 
It is asking when opening the camera

Answer (score 7):

If you want to save data you don't need any permission for that on iOS, it is allowed by default. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)  It is the only reason why it is not supported by react-native-permissions.

Comment: What you mean is that i can download let's say audio or video files and save it to ios by default without permission been asked??