# Flutter picking files from iOS file and folder app with File Picker not asking permission

Tags: ios, flutter, permissions

I am picking files stored in **iOS file and folder app** using **file_picker**. When running, android asked for storage permission but on iOS, there is no permission asked and I am able to pick files from the file and folder app.

Is there a way to make sure to ask for permission for iOS or no need to ask for permission for this case? 
If we can ask for permission, which ***permission*** is it?

As my understanding, if there is any permission needed (*eg, for **camera**, NSCameraUsageDescription is needed*) and if I don't give the permission in plist, the app will break. 
Right now there is no permission added in ***plist*** for **files and folders app** access and the app didn't break either.

The following is my code using file_picker package.

```
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      withData: true,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx'],
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowMultiple: true,
    );
```

I already tried with permission_handler. In the package's doc, it says to use Permission.storage but when I debug with this, the permission seems to have already granted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64646086)

Comment: I already tried with permission_handler. In it's doc, it says to use `Permission.storage` but when I debug with this, the permission seems to has already granted.

Comment: maybe you are missing implementation try restarting the app

Comment: Did you added permissions to be requested in `info.plist` ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53089331/18139940. It said IOS storage permission is allowed by default and explanation is here [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).